# Square root of a number without math.sqrt

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

```
def sqrt(number):
    number = root**2
    return root

def area_triangle(a, b, c):
    x = (a+b+c)/2
    result = x*(x-a)*(x-b)*(x-c)
    print (sqrt(result))

area_triangle(4,5,6)
```

This gives me a name error which "NameError: name 'root' is not defined"

I want to do this without math.sqrt or`root = number**(1/2)`
How can I solve this without using these two and why doesn't the same error occurs as "NameError: name 'number' is not defined"  if I use the alternative?

Comment: well root is indeed not defined. should be root = number**2 or what ever you're trying to accomplish here.

Comment: Why don't you want to use `math.sqrt` or one-half power? I see two main reasons to avoid that:when you need more precision than the 15-17 significant digits that `math.sqrt` and one-half power provide, or you are working with large integers and you want an exact answer for the integer part of the square root. The `decimal` module handles the first case, and for the second case you can do a web search to find such a function.

Comment: I'm trying to learn all different methods, I don't want to learn just one way and left others out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python is not an equation solver, like Wolfram Alpha. It is a language that executes the instructions you give it.

```
root = number**(1/2)
```

is an instruction. It says: take `number`, which already exists, and raise it to the 1/2 power; name the result `root`.

```
number = root**2
```

is also an instruction, but not the one you want. It says: take `root`, which should already exist, and raise it to the 2nd power; name the result `number`. But `root` actually doesn't already exist, so you get an error.

The two options you give are the most sensible ones for finding a square root - not sure why you want to avoid them. You could, of course, implement a square-root-finding algorithm yourself, but it's definitely much more straightforward to use the built-in solutions! A small change could be using `number**(.5)` or `math.pow(number,1/2)` (this is, of course, equivalent to your 1/2).